# Combing results from union all into one row when some columns have different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using union all to combine the results of two select statements.  I'm trying to group the results by the date_requested column.  I need to combine both queries into one row if the dates are the same.  Right now, it's keeping two rows for the same date.  This is because the tracking_id column is different between the two rows.  Since I'm not worried about tracking_id for this, how do I bypass this and combine them anyway?  Thanks.

```
(select trv.requested_date, trv.requested_status
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr
where t.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, trv.requested_date order by trv.requested_date asc )
union all 
(select mlc.requested_date, mlc.requested_status
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr, tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc
where trv.tracking_id=mlc.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and mlc.payment_status='pending' and mlc.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, mlc.requested_date order by mlc.requested_date asc )
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
select requested_date, requested_status
from (select trv.requested_date as requested_date, trv.requested_status as requested_status
        from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as trk , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr
        where trk.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=trk.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
        and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.requested_date asc 
        union all
        select mlc.requested_date as requested date, mlc.requested_status as requested_status
        from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as trk , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr, tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc
        where trv.tracking_id=mlc.tracking_id  and off.id=trk.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
        and mlc.payment_status='pending' and mlc.requested_status='declined'  group by mlc.requested_date asc ) t 
group by requested_date
```

UDPATE II: I deleted the aliases from the selections and that seems to have fixed the syntax error.  I'll do more testing to make sure it works for a variety of cases.  Thanks for the help.  I didn't know you can't use aliases for your selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows are exactly the same except for tracking_id, just remove that from your list and use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. If you have other differences, you may prefer to use `GROUP BY` on your final results, so that you can use aggregate functions on other values that are different.

Comment: I am using group by already.  Is there a way to use group by for the entire union?  Is that what you are saying?  I've heard union can sometimes get rid of rows, which is why I was hesitant to use it.  Thanks, I'm just learning.

Comment: Yes - you can turn your current query into a subquery using `SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM (<big query>) t GROUP BY col1, col2, ... ;`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code above with what I'm trying now, and I get a syntax error.

Comment: Looks like you're getting closer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `tracking_id` from the subqueries and use `union`:

```
(select trv.requested_date, trv.requested_status
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv, tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr
where t.id=trv.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and trv.payment_status='pending' and trv.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, trv.requested_date order by trv.requested_date asc )
union
(select mlc.requested_date, mlc.requested_status
from  tbl_trackvalue as trv ,tbl_tracking as t , tbl_offers as off , tblusers as usr, tbl_mailchimp_trackvalue as mlc
where trv.tracking_id=mlc.tracking_id  and off.id=t.offer_id and  usr.id=trv.tr_user_id and usr.id='1454' 
and mlc.payment_status='pending' and mlc.requested_status='declined'  group by trv.tr_user_id, mlc.requested_date order by mlc.requested_date asc )
```